# Module cannot be found from tests dir

Tags: rust

I have the following structure:

```
root/
  |--src/
    |--main.rs
    |--api.rs
  |--tests/
    |--my_test.rs
  |--Cargo.lock
  |--Cargo.toml
```

The crate's main file is `root/src/main.rs` and in that main file I have:

```
pub mod api;
pub use api::*;
```

But when I try to import the `api` in the test file like so:

```
use crate::src::api::*;

// also tried `use crate::api::*;`
```

I get the error that the import cannot be found. How do I make the source file visible to the tests file?

I'd like to keep the tests separate from the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Integration-testing is only supported for `[lib]` crates, not binary crates such as the one created for `src/main.rs`, you should put all code that you want to test into a library crate (`src/lib.rs`) or it's modules and import them like you would with an external crate using the crates name.

So with a simple `src/lib.rs` which you can just add to your project and will be automatically detected by `cargo`

```rust
pub mod api;
```

you can then use it from `src/main.rs` or your `tests/my_test.rs` like this

```rust
use crate_name::api::*;
```

where `crate_name` is the one you specify in your `Cargo.toml`

Comment: Doing this approach broke the actual app's build. Is it because I cannot have `lib.rs` and `main.rs` in the same place? 

P.S. I tried something else (not involving `lib.rs`): I moved the `/tests` dir under `/src` and it solved it. But I was wondering if it would’ve worked in a different way, completely separating the tests from the source.

Comment: You definitely can have `lib.rs` and `main.rs` in the same project, you just can't put the `mod` statements in both.

Comment: I see... so that's what was screwing up my imports and consequently the build. 
So, the approach would be that whatever I've declared as mod's in `main` will have to be declared only in `lib` and then in `main` I only declare the `lib`. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Almost, you don't declare `lib` as module in `main` but simply `use crate_name::*;` to import contents of the library crate.